# Choosing a radio button from its labels with Capybara

Tags: capybara

I have a dynamically generated form that looks like this:

```
Do you like Pizza?
[ ] Yes   [ ] No
```

The HTML looks like this:

```
<form>
  <div class="field">
    <label>Do you like Pizza?</label>
    <input
      type="radio" value="true" 
      id="reply_set_replies_attrs_0_pizza_true"
      name="reply_set[replies_attrs][0][pizza]">
    </input>
    <label for="reply_set_replies_attrs_0_pizza_true">Yes<label>
    <input
      type="radio" value="false" 
      id="reply_set_replies_attrs_0_pizza_false"
      name="reply_set[replies_attrs][0][pizza]">
    </input>
    <label for="reply_set_replies_attrs_0_pizza_false">No<label>
  </div>
</form>
```

I'd like to get check those radio buttons with Capybara. How can I do this? I don't always know the `id`s of the radio buttons, because there's a few of them and when I also ask about Popcorn and Chicken I don't want to depend on knowing their order.

Is there a way to do something like...

```
field = find_label("Do you like pizza?").parent('field')
yes = field.find_label('Yes')
yes.click
```

?

Comment: I think there are a couple of typos in your html - (1) you have a closing `</field>` instead of a `</div>` and (2) both of the labels say "Yes" (presumably one should be "No").

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that when using `find`, the `:text` option does a partial text match. Therefore, you could find the div directly:

```
find('div.field', :text => 'Do you like Pizza?').choose('Yes')
```

(Also using `choose` makes radio button selection easier.)

Answer (score 2):

not bad!

```
label = find('label', :text => "Do you like Pizza?")
parent = label.find(:xpath, '..')
parent.find_field("Yes").click
```